# Open multiple independant instances of Word 2007

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2007

Since MS Word 2007 there seems to be a change in how Documents are opened. In older Versions, each Document could be opened in a completely independant Word Window. Now, all seem to be opened in one single Process, which is currently not the desired behaviour.

I try to open multiple Copies of a Mailmerge Document (all in different folders and named differently), to speed up the process of creating the letters to round about 10k recipients. The documents are automatically created and printed using VBA.

In older Versions of Word I could open each Document in an independant process of Word by just starting another instance of the application and then opening the document. Each Word Process did not interfere with the others so that they all could work simultaneously.

Now I don't find a way to run them separately. If I do an Apllication.Visible = False in one of them, all Documents become invisible. I can't start more than one macro as it's not possible to run multiple macros in the same instance of Word.

Does anybody know, how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are opening the documents, say by double-clicking in Explorer, you are using the same instance of Word.

I believe you are being made to believe there are separate instances of Word.

1. Click the File Tab then click Options.
2. Click Advanced.
3. Scroll down to the Display section

Have you ticked ‘Show all windows in the taskbar’?

Regardless try this code that uses CreateObject("word.Application")

Tested in Word 2010.

```
Sub SecondWordInstance()

Dim wordApp As Word.Application

Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = True

MsgBox " Second Word instance should be visible. " & _
  "Click on the new Word button in the taskabr. " & _
  "Try a macro.  Do not click OK yet."

wordApp.Visible = False

MsgBox " Second Word instance should be hidden."

wordApp.Visible = True
wordApp.Quit

MsgBox " Second Word instance should have quit"

exitRoutine:
Set wordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I alredy know that there are no independant Word 2007 Application Windows by checking the task manager. There always is only one process. But the idea forcing another instance by VBA code works fine - could have come up with that by myself :-|